# App rejected for in-app purchase in Apple Review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I had app in App store in which I have in-app purchase to unlock some features. But in the current versions of the I thought of removing all the in-app purchase within the app and give all features for free.

But Apple has reject my app for the following reason :

> From Apple
>
> 4.0 BEFORE YOU SUBMIT: INFO NEEDED
>
> Information Needed
>
> We have begun the review of your app but aren't able to continue because we can't locate the In-App Purchase(s) within your app.
>
> At your earliest opportunity, please reply to this message providing the steps for locating the In-App Purchase(s) in your app.

Please let me whether should I inform apple review team about this in review notes or should I remove all in-app purchase from sale.

I fear removing in-app purchase from will affect the existing user using older version of the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would reply stating that in-app purchases are being removed and see how you go.

Comment: You should provide the info about in-app purchase has been removed in the  Note,  and about the existing user yes, may be it will affect cause they have paid for some features and now the features is free ,so may be u can put some note regarding to user that we have changed this thing.

Comment: @ravi.p: Thanks for your suggestion. We have made in-app as free.

Comment: @Arasuvel Welcome...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit the app by adding an explanation in review notes section. This will accepted by Apple. Also your app will get approved.